# Flutter range slider with single label

Tags: flutter, rangeslider

I'm trying to make a custom range slider like the one on this image:

https://prnt.sc/t4etpj

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

What you're looking for is a widget called [`RangeSlider`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/RangeSlider-class.html) from the material library.

```
RangeSlider(
  values: const RangeValues(1.5, 4.5);,
  onChanged: (RangeValues values) {
    // callback
  },
);
```

If you want to exactly reproduce what you've shown in the picture, you must create one by your own (preferably with a state management library rather than using plain `setState`, but that's not required).

Comment: I've created a RangeSlider already as you wrote Alberto, so I'll need to create a custom one after all?
Can you please provide some example on how to do it?

Comment: It's not going to be an easy and quick job. In my opinion, you could look for: flutter_bloc (state management), AnimatedBuilder (for animations) and the Stack/Positioned widgets.